# Best way to filter different date ranges Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a transactions table which records transactions, versions and dates of versions. I want to filter by a date range, but if the last last version date falls within the date range I want to include all the transaction versions e.g.

```
Transaction_ID | Version | Version_Date
----------------------------------------
001            |1        |31/12/2020
001            |2        |01/01/2021
001            |3        |02/01/2021
001            |4        |03/02/2021
002            |1        |29/12/2020
002            |2        |30/12/2020
002            |3        |31/12/2020
```

If I have a filter on date range 01/01/2021-03/01/2021 the query should return all the versions of transaction 001 (even the version 1 with date 31/12/2020) but will ignore transaction 002 since none if its version dates fall within the specified range.

How can I achieve this in oracle sql?

Answer (score 0):

Use `exists`:

```
select t.*
from transactions t
where exists (select 1
              from transactions t2
              where t2.transaction_id = t.transaction_id and
                    t2.version_date between :start and :end
             );
```

I don't really recommend `between` for dates -- particularly in Oracle where dates can have hidden time components.  I would actually suggest:

```
              where t2.transaction_id = t.transaction_id and
                    t2.version_date >= :start and
                    t2.version_date < :end + interval '1' day
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a try.  The date range is subject to change, and there will be more transactions and versions.

Comment: @professor_kal . . . `:start` and `:end` are intended to represent parameters with the data range you care about.